# Trying to define a Mockito-stub executes the mocked method. Why?

Tags: mockito, springockito

We are trying to define a UnitTest where we mock an object which I here called `x` for simplicity:

```java
...
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import org.kubek2k.springockito.annotations.SpringockitoContextLoader;
import org.kubek2k.springockito.annotations.WrapWithSpy;
...

@ContextConfiguration(
    loader = SpringockitoContextLoader.class,
    inheritLocations = true)
public class SyncServiceIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    @WrapWithSpy
    private EventDrivenIssueDeliveryConfirmer x;

    ...

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ...
        doNothing().when(x).foobar(any(Event.class));
    }

    ...
```

i.e. we want our UT (not shown here) to later NOT call the method `foobar` on that object `x`.

Strange enough we get an NPE during initialization of this UT-class. The NPE is thrown by method `foobar()`, when the passed argument is null.

As turned out this call with argument `null` happens in the line `doNothing()...` in the `setup`-method which in our understanding is supposed to just *define* the mock-object's stubbing. But instead it evaluates the `any(Event.class)`-expression which apparently yields `null` and with that result it then calls the `foobar(...)`-method on `x` which causes the NPE.

Besides the NullPointerException we also get an error message from Mockito:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
... <stack trace omitted for brevity>

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at ch.sst.integration.SyncServiceIntegrationTest .setUp(SyncServiceIntegrationTest.java:69)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
... <examples omitted for brevity>

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at ch.sst.integration.SyncServiceIntegrationTest .setUp(SyncServiceIntegrationTest.java:69)
...
```

Why is that so??? Why is our stubbing considered "unfinished"? What are we missing here?

*Later addition:*

The issue seems to have to do with the fact that class
`EventDrivenIssueDeliveryConfirmer` is marked with @Transactional. Removing/commenting that lets the UT succeed. But of course that's no workaround - we need that annotation.
At least this provides a hint in which direction to search. The wrapping caused by @Transactional and the wrapping done by Mockito seem to step on each other's foot here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but with a totally different setup: kotlin, mockito and, of course, mockito-kotlin.
I comment on this issue because maybe somebody will come to this question with the kotlin mockito problem in the future? I sure did. Anyhow.

When not declaring a method as open in kotlin it's compiled as a final method which can't be mocked by mockito-kotlin. As a result the method gets executed which to me is kind of weird but that's what it does. It's mentioned in the mockito-kotlin github issues under https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/issues/314